# How to connect firebase with flutter web?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web, dart-null-safety

I have a flutter app that works fine in android phone but when I am try to run it on web it crashes and showing following error.

> Exception has occurred. "Error: Invalid argument(s): object cannot be
> a num, string, bool, or null
> C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/*internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart
> 266:49      throw*
> C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/js_patch.dart
> 43:7                    fromBrowserObject
> packages/firebase_core_web/src/firebase_core_web.dart 64:20
> get [_ignoredServiceScripts]
> packages/firebase_core_web/src/firebase_core_web.dart 115:28
> _initializeCore C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart
> 84:54                runBody
> C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart
> 123:5                _async
> packages/firebase_core_web/src/firebase_core_web.dart 107:31
> [_initializeCore]
> packages/firebase_core_web/src/firebase_core_web.dart 149:11
> initializeApp
> C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart
> 84:54                runBody
> C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart
> 123:5                _async
> packages/firebase_core_web/src/firebase_core_web.dart 145:44
> initializeApp packages/firebase_core/src/firebase.dart 40:47
> initializeApp
> C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart
> 84:54                runBody
> C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart
> 123:5                _async packages/firebase_core/src/firebase.dart
> 36:43
> initializeApp packages/afterdefence_web/main.dart 31:18
> main
> C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart
> 84:54                runBody
> C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart
> 123:5                _async packages/afterdefence_web/main.dart 19:18
> main$ web_entrypoint.dart 24:31
>
> C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart
> 334:14  _checkAndCall
> C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart
> 339:39  dcall
> C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/ui/initialization.dart
> 77:15                                  
> C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart
> 45:50                
> C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart
> 1653:54                                              runUnary
> C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart
> 147:18                                        handleValue
> C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart
> 766:44                                        handleValueCallback
> C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart
> 795:13                                        _propagateToListeners
> C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart
> 566:5                                         [_completeWithValue]
> C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart
> 639:7                                         callback
> C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart
> 40:11                                  _microtaskLoop
> C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart
> 49:5                                   _startMicrotaskLoop
> C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart
> 166:15                "

main functions

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
    webRecaptchaSiteKey: 'recaptcha-v3-site-key',
  );


  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

    This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
    the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
  -->
  <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="afterdefence_web">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />

  <title>AfterDefence Web</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

  <script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->

  <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="module">
    // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.4/firebase-app.js";
    import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.4/firebase-analytics.js";
    // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries
  
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "",
      authDomain: "",
      projectId: "",
      storageBucket: "",
      messagingSenderId: "",
      appId: "",
      measurementId: ""
    };
  
    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
  </script>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function (ev) {
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        }
      }).then(function (engineInitializer) {
        return engineInitializer.initializeEngine();
      }).then(function (appRunner) {
        return appRunner.runApp();
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you refer to this [blog](https://medium.com/multiverse-software/firebase-on-flutter-mobile-and-web-284812056c5c) and [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=web) , is it helpful?